# Define a list of dictionaries in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way of defining, in the Variables section of a robot framework file (.rst), a list of dictionaries (or list of lists)?
This should be very straighforward, even for a Robot novice, but I'm struggling to do it.
To make things clear, I need something like this:

```
`*** Variables ***
 @{list_of_dicts}    [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 25},
                      {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 30},
                      {'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 35}]

*** Keywords ***
Example Keyword
    : FOR    ${dict}    IN    @{list_of_dicts}
    \    Log    ${dict['name']} is ${dict['age']} years old`
```

I tried varying the posted code in several ways.

Robot Version: 2.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regretfully, no, it's painfully not-straightforward using just RF syntax - you have to define each dict as a var, and then include them individually in the list variable:

```
*** Variables ***
&{dict1}    key1=value1    key2=value2
&{dict2}    keyY=valueY    keyX=valueX
@{list_of_dicts}    ${dict1}    ${dict2}
```

---

There is an alternative though - the inline evaluation technique; it for sure will work inside cases and keywords *(I've used it for exactly this purpose - a list of dicts to later serialize as json)*, but I don't know does it work in the Variables section, you have to try it out.
If it does, it'll look like this - a direct python statement or expression inside `${{}}`(double curly brackets):

```
*** Variables ***
${list_of_dicts}    ${{ [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 35}] }}
```

If it doesn't *(work there)* - you can do it in a keyword, call `Set Suite Variable` on the variable, and have that keyword called in `Suite Setup` (*that goes under the moto "life is a series of workarounds" :)*)

Comment: The alternative solution is what I'm looking for. But I keep getting "Invalid variable name '${{ [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 25}'". Tried defining it in the variables section and in a keywork using "Set Suite Variable".

Comment: If I fail to make the second approach to work, I will use the first one you posted. The only  drawback is if someone forgets to put a created dict in the list.

Comment: I just noticed in your question you gave your RobotFramework version: 2.9.2; that is a very old one, ancient even. It for sure doesn't support the inline evaluation syntax; I'd highly recommend upgrading if that's possible in your environment, you'll get a ton of other benefits too.

Comment: I just searched for the version that inline evaluation was introduced: 3.2. Unfortunately, I can't upgrade to a newer one. So, I'll be using the first solution you posted. Thank you very much! Thanks for @JaPyR too, which provided an equally good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not so straightforward. I would suggest to user `.yaml` file for storing such variables. So in your case:

```yaml
Persons:
  - name: Alice
    age: 25
  - name: Bob
    age: 30
  - name: Charlie
    age: 35
```

and latter use it in robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    persons.yaml

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test Case
    FOR    ${person}    IN    @{PERSONS}
        Log    ${person["name"]} is ${person["age"]} years old
    END
```

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks! It would be better if I could define the data in the rst file though. Defining the data in a separate file would differ too much (maybe) from the pattern we already use in the tests.